# Disable a division

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable a division using the click function

*For Example:*
I am having a **search box** on my website. After clicking the search box all the things in my website must be **disabled** except the search box suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Show your search results in a modal.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Thanks for your time . Can u tell me an example for this.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I have used backdrop modal.But it thanks whole website into inactive

Comment: By disable, I think, you want to show an overlay so that focus is only on search box and the suggestions.. Right?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ  Thanks guys for your time. I found a solution. I have created a division and makes that a position fixed

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. 
Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). 
**DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. 
Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The `pointer-events` property allows for control over how HTML elements respond to mouse/touch events – including CSS hover/active states, click/tap events in Javascript, and whether or not the cursor is visible.

> add `pointer-events: none;` CSS in div for disable

```js
$("div").on("click",function(){
 alert("test");
});
```

```css
div{width:50px;height:50px;margin:5px;}
#div1{background-color:pink;}
#div2{background-color:lightgrey;}
.disable{pointer-events: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">enable</div>
<div id="div2" class="disable">disable</div>
```